# Workflow that is started by the information management policy is not assigning task to user

Tags: workflow, document-library, task-list, information-management

Our foundation has created a record retention policy that will be implemented on our new SharePoint 2013 site. I have created custom columns for "start retention date" "review date" "data owner" and "retention category".

Currently there is a workflow that will add the retention category (1 year, 3 years, 7 years) to the start retention date that then populates the review date. This works perfectly.

I have started on a new workflow that I have associated with a information management policy that will run a timer job every night. This workflow is based off of the review date and looks like this:

```
if Review Date equals(ignoring time) Today{
    Assign Review Document for Retention to Data Owner
    then email Data Owner
else
    Comment: Retention period not reached
}
then Stop the workflow and log Complete
```

The workflow is triggering and starting but it does not create a task for the Data Owner or send an email. It just logs complete in the workflow history list.

I am certain it has something to do with how I am setting up the workflow (using SP Designer 2013).

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I have resolved this by creating a new document library and updating the workflow to just assign the task and then end the workflow.